# How can I tell subprocess to answer "y" to a commandline question?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, automation, subprocess

I'm automating an ffmpeg command but when the file exists already, it asks me if I have to "Overwrite [y/N]" and it stalls the entire script until I have to enter "y" myself in the console. How can I automate that?

```
for file in all_files_in_dir:
    output = file.split('.')[0]
    subprocess.call(f'ffmpeg -hide_banner -i {file} -map 0:s:1 {output}.srt')
```

I have to enter "y" myself (as  seen in green), then press enter everytime a file is already found. The answer will be "y", so I can hardcode the answer "y" if need be.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use [the `ffmpeg` bindings for Python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) instead of finagling a command-line utility (designed for human-in-the-loop interaction) to do what you want?

Comment: I didn't know that was an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-y` to ffmpeg args. Add `-n` for no.